# Vertically center element with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically center 'design' label as well as '21nov'.

```
<div class="row">             
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1">                
         <a href="/job/52"><span class="jobtitle">designer</span></a>
         <span class="companyname"> @Subiaco</span>
         <div class="salary">90.000$ - 100.000$</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3">   
        <span class="label label-success">design</span>                         
     </div>                         
    <div class="col-xs-2">                   
      21 nov.
    </div>                 
</div>
```

**Current design :** http://jsfiddle.net/8FM3n/

[image]

---

**Expected design**:
[image]

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it isn't dynamic content of varying heights, you can use `line-height`.

```
.row .col-xs-3, .row .col-xs-2 {
    line-height: 49px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8FM3n/1/) - it's vertically aligned now, though you might want to apply the styling to a different class so it won't affect other row elements.